# android: how to insert button into listview that are populated from the database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I'm very new in developing andorids.I want to insert button into every row in the listview that are populated by mysql. i have been following this tutorial from
http://cwpdev.blogspot.com/2014/03/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html and i'm eager to learn!

```
public class RollCall extends Activity {
    private String jsonResult;
    private String url =  "http://rektitmate.com/webservices/student_details.php";
    private ListView listView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_roll_call);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
         accessWebService();

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_roll_call, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Async Task to access the web
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return answer;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Listout();
        }
    }// end async task
    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        // passes values for the urls string array
        task.execute(new String[] { url });
    }
    // build hash set for list view
    public void Listout() {
        List<Map<String, String>> StudentList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("student");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("student name");
                String number = jsonChildNode.optString("stuid");
                String outPut = number + "." + name;
                StudentList.add(createStudent("student", outPut));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, StudentList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[] { "student" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }
    private HashMap<String, String> createStudent(String name, String number) {
        HashMap<String, String> studentNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        studentNameNo.put(name, number);
        return studentNameNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have that Button in every list item layout or to add it dynamically?

Comment: i want to have that buttons in every row in the list

Comment: Then you have to build a custom XML layout, not using a native android layout.

Comment: owh ok i think i got the ideas. I will try now. Thanks champ. I will try to do it

Comment: Are you still working on this? I have done the same and adding buttons in a ListView is common.

Comment: @The Original Android  Could you provide an example of creating a listview with buttons in it populated from mysql database?  And buttons should execute a certain method/function when clicked.  I'm trying to do the same thing.